# disable dates using jquery inside gridview control

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a gridview which contains a textbox control. I need to show the calendar for the user to pick the date and certain dates are to be disabled using jquery. I found a post on stackoverflow that talked about how to disable certain dates. I am done with that part, except not sure how to pass the textbox control to this jquery function. Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    var enabledDays = ['09/21/2011', '10/05/2011', '10/19/2011', '11/02/2011', '11/16/2011'];

    /* utility functions */
    function editDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
            if (new Date(enabledDays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
                return [true];
            }
        }
        return [false];
    }
    /* create datepicker */
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= txtInHomeDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
            beforeShow: springDate,
            beforeShowDay: editDays,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            buttonImage: 'images/cal.gif',
            buttonText: 'Choose date',
            firstDay: 1,
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            showOn: 'both',
            showAnim: 'fadeIn',
            onSelect: function() { $(this).trigger("onchange", null); }
        });
        function springDate() {
            var defaultMin = new Date();
            var defaultMax = new Date();
            var Min = defaultMin;
            var Max = defaultMax;
            // make valid date from hiddenfied value format is MM/dd/yyyy  
            dateMin = $('#<%= hfStDate.ClientID %>').val();
            dateMin = new Date(dateMin);
            dateMax = $('#<%= hfEndDate.ClientID %>').val();
            dateMax = new Date(dateMax);
            if (dateMin && dateMax) {
                Min = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate());
                Max = new Date(dateMax.getFullYear(), dateMax.getMonth(), dateMax.getDate());
            }
            return {
                minDate: Min,
                maxDate: Max
            };
        }
    });
}
```

<....

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="In-Home Date">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfStDate" runat="server" Value="09/01/2011" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfEndDate" runat="server" Value="11/30/2011" />  
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInHomeDate" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Currently, it errors out since the jquery function won't find the txtInHomeDate. Could I get some help as I am pretty close to get this done? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class instead of ID:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInHomeDate" runat="server" CssClass='textDate' />
```

Your JS code would looks like the following:

```
$('.textDate').datepicker({ ...
```

This will loop through all the textboxes with the given class and apply datepicker to them.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Now the calendar shows up on the gridview. But the start and enddates don't show up now. I changed the HiddenFields to TextBox and uses the cssclass instead, not working.

Comment: +1 for the excruciatingly straightforward selector, which I managed to overcomplicate.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can't find your text box because each row in the Grid View contains a TextBox with a different ID. If your TextBox is always in the same column, I'd suggest using the eq  selector to get all the TextBoxes at once, like:

```
$("tr :eq(3)").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        // setup here
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Artem's selector is definitely more optimal than mine -- the class selector is much faster. If you need to get the hidden fields, you could use his selector above, like so:

```
$(".textDate").each(function() {
    var $startDate = $(this).prevAll("[id$='hfStDate']");
    var $endDate = $(this).prevAll("[id$='hfEndDate']");
    // Datepicker setup goes here.
}
```

**Edit 2:** `prev` is incorrect -- it should've been `prevAll`. This feels very hack-y to me, and I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish this task, but regardless... Here's a link to a [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwiscarson/yYL2m/7/) of this, without the datepicker.

Comment: Hi jwiscarson, i tried setting the startdate and enddate to what you have mentioned above, but the calendar displays only this month's dates (i.e. December 2010) with all dates disabled. It doesn't navigate to previous or next months.

Comment: This did the trick.$("#<%= gvDetails.ClientID %>").find("input[id$='hfStDate']")

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you - Artem and jwiscarson.

Comment: Unfortunately, you now get the unenviable task of choosing which answer to accept. I updated my answer with the correct function -- prev isn't quite right. Also, if you can, you should try to use attributes only in your selectors. Tag prefixes slow them down.

Comment: I think I would have to go with artem as he provided the idea to actually make the calendar work inside a gridview. I wish I could mark your answer as well but the forum lets you mark only one.